# Pressing tab with tkinter Listboxes moves the "Active" underscore but not the cursor

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, listbox

```
l1=Listbox()
l1.pack(side=LEFT)
l1.insert(END, *xrange(1,4))

l2=Listbox()
l2.pack(side=RIGHT)
l2.insert(END, *'abc')
```

When I press tab, the underscore jumps to the other Listbox, but the cursor only joins in when I start using the up/down arrows. Is it possible to make it hop along together with the underscore, on pressing tab?

**Edit**: This is done by binding the Tab key to invoke the select_set() method on the active item:

```
l1.bind('<Tab>', lambda e: l2.select_set(l2.index(ACTIVE)))
l2.bind('<Tab>', lambda e: l1.select_set(l1.index(ACTIVE)))
```

- l.index(ACTIVE) returns the index of the active item, which is the one with the underscore after Tab is pressed.
- It is then set to be "selected" using l.select_set(), which moves the cursor to it as well.
- the "e" after lambda is required since any function called from a tkinter bind is implicitly given an event object, though it isn't used in any way here.

Hope this comes handy.

Comment: I eventually found out that the underscore (or the 'dotbox', depending on the `activestyle` property of a Listbox) marks the active item, whereas the cursor is for selected item(s). Since Tab only changes the ACTIVE attribute to the item in the appropiate Listbox, that item should also be marked as "selected" to move the cursor to it. This is done by binding the Tab key to allow that extra manouver. I've Edited the question to show how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underscore and cursor represent different attributes of Listbox items -

- The underscore marking, which is the default `activestyle` attribute
  of a Listbox, shows the active item.
- The cursor is for (a) selected item(s).

The Tab key, by default, alternates the "active" state in this context, so it does not affect the cursor.

To change the cursor position, we need to set the active item to be the (a) selected item as well. I've done so by binding the Tab key to lambda functions that perform this additional manouver:

```
l1.bind('<Tab>', lambda e: l2.select_set(l2.index(ACTIVE)))
l2.bind('<Tab>', lambda e: l1.select_set(l1.index(ACTIVE)))
```

The active index is given as an argument to the appropriate `select_set()`, which then moves the cursor over the underscored item.

**Note:** I think that for a more general case, the event `e` should be used to pick up the active item, rather than referring to the Listboxes directly. However, this seems to work fine for 2 listboxes.